# close previous dropdown in jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a menu in my WordPress theme, I have to close the previous dropdown and open current dropdown, I tried bwelow script but it not working.

Would you help me out ?

```js
$('ul#left-primary-menu li').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  //$(this).find('> ul').slideToggle();
  if (!$(this).next('.sub-menu').is(':visible')) {
    $('.sub-menu').hide(500);
    $(this).next('.sub-menu').slideToggle('fast');
  }
});
```

```css
ul#left-primary-menu ul.sub-menu {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul id="left-primary-menu" class="menu">
  <li id="menu-item-663" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-318 current_page_item menu-item-663"><a href="#" aria-current="page">Home</a></li>

  <li id="menu-item-23" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-23">Tech
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li id="menu-item-602" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-602"><a href="#">Headphones</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-603" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-603"><a href="#">Smartphones</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li id="menu-item-627" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-has-children menu-item-627">Accessories
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li id="menu-item-625" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-625"><a href="#">Access1</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-594" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-594"><a href="#">Access2</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-647" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-647"><a href="#">Access3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li id="menu-item-8" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-8">Footwear
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li id="menu-item-596" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-596"><a href="#">Rain Boots</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

</ul>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `find()` instead of `next()` while searching for `.sub-menu`

```js
$('ul#left-primary-menu li').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  //$(this).find('> ul').slideToggle();
  if (!$(this).find('.sub-menu').is(':visible')) {
    $('.sub-menu').hide(500);
    $(this).find('.sub-menu').slideToggle('fast');
  }
});
```

```css
ul#left-primary-menu ul.sub-menu {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul id="left-primary-menu" class="menu">
  <li id="menu-item-663" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-318 current_page_item menu-item-663"><a href="#" aria-current="page">Home</a></li>

  <li id="menu-item-23" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-23">Tech
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li id="menu-item-602" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-602"><a href="#">Headphones</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-603" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-603"><a href="#">Smartphones</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li id="menu-item-627" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-has-children menu-item-627">Accessories
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li id="menu-item-625" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-625"><a href="#">Access1</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-594" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-594"><a href="#">Access2</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-647" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-647"><a href="#">Access3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li id="menu-item-8" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-8">Footwear
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li id="menu-item-596" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-596"><a href="#">Rain Boots</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

</ul>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, Yes, It's working. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with something like this. Add classes and go away from psuedo selectors. It's a bit of jQuery chaining, but this is a quick POC.

```
const $menu = $('ul#left-primary-menu');
const $menuItem = $('ul#left-primary-menu li');
$menuItem.on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $menu.find('li.active').removeClass('active').find('.sub-menu').slideToggle('fast');
  $(this).addClass('active').find('.sub-menu').slideToggle('fast');
});
```

Comment: You might want to add `.not(this)` to the first jQuery chain to ensure that both statements don't try to act on the clicked element.
ie: `$menu.find('li.active').not(this).removeClass('active').find('.sub-menu').slideToggle('fast');`